# Implementing zLib compression in Flex and Java

Tags: java, apache-flex, compression, zlib

I am sending some JSON data from my Flex application to the Java side for business processing. Now on top of that, I have added some code to compress(zLib) the data at Flex side and then pass it through Request and uncompress the same at java side. 
But at the java layer, the uncompressed data is still not in readable/usable format.

Putting the code in here for reference.

**Flex code for encoding**

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeObject(JSON.encode(someObj));
bytes.position = 0;
bytes.compress();
variables.encodeJSONStr = bytes;
requester.data = variables;
loader.load(requester);
```

**Java code for decoding**

```
String json = req.getParameter("encodeJSONStr");
byte[] input = json.getBytes();
Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
decompresser.setInput(input);
byte[] result = new byte[1000];
int resultLength=0;
resultLength = decompresser.inflate(result);
decompresser.end();
String outputString = new String(result, 0, resultLength, "UTF-8");
System.out.println("\n\n resultLength>>>"+resultLength); // O/P comes as Zero
```

Can someone point put the issue in here or some better approach for compression of data when sending from Flex to Java ?

Comment: The issue is solved. I sent the ByteArray from flex side and retrived the same in Java with InputStream, got the ByteArray and inflated it.:)

Comment: Could you share how the inflating was done on the server?

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I wrote a short post about sending compressed data between flex/java, maybe it helps: http://cornelcreanga.com/2008/07/actionscript-compressing-strings/

Answer (score 0):

First you should try if Flex does the zLib compression properly (by uncompressing the data sent with another tool).

On the Java side you can try to use the [InflaterInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html) which is easier to handle than the more low level Inflater. I had some issues with the Java native implementation and ended up using the [jZlib](http://www.jcraft.com/jzlib/) which offers a zlib compression uncompression in pure Java.